# Spring JPA: How to insert/update new item with unique column when using Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to create a new Product with a category. If the category doesn't exist then also create the category. So far so good with this use case.

My second use case comes when I want to create another product with the same category. Since I have my Category entity with unique name then when I call my service it throws the duplicate error key. What I want is to be able to create the second product and update the category to have this product.

This is my Category Entity

```
package com.smolano.cupboard.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

This is my Product Entity

```
package com.smolano.cupboard.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_categories",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")}
    )
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
    private String barCode;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }
}
```

My category repository

```
package com.smolano.cupboard.repositories;

import com.smolano.cupboard.entities.Category;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
}
```

and my product repository

```
package com.smolano.cupboard.repositories;

import com.smolano.cupboard.entities.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Rest of my code can be found here
https://github.com/santfirax/backend-product-store-java

Comment: I have tried some solutions that i've seen on SO but it doesn't work.  One was to implement hascode and equals method but that caused infinite recursion when calling the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I don't see a necessity of having many to many relationship. one to many can serve the purpose, where one category can have multiple products and you can create multiple products using the same category which is unique by name.

If you still want to achieve it, you need to have a new table with the combination of primary keys of both tables and that is going to be the unique combination.
refer these pages for more info [1](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) and [2](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-spring-data-jpa-part-8-many-to-man) with visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `CascadeType.REMOVE` for many-to-many associations, since it may generate too many queries and remove more records than you expected. [Here](https://thorben-janssen.com/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/) is an article that explains this behavior in details. Since you're using `CascadeType.ALL` in your mapping it also includes `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

Regarding adding/updating new categories to product entity. It would be helpful to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Since in your example `Category.name` should be unique and basically you distinguish categories by their names, then your implementations may look like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Category))
            return false;
        Category other = (Category) o;
        return (this.name == null && other.name == null) || (this.name != null && this.name.equals(other.name));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
```

This way you'll make sure that your `Product.categories` field will not contain categories with the same name.

Assuming that your entity mapping have `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`, your service class may look similar to following:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public Product createProduct(Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    public Product saveCategoryInProduct(Long productId, Category category) {
        return productRepository
                .findById(productId)
                .map(product -> addCategory(product, category))
                .map(productRepository::save)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

    private Product addCategory(Product product, Category category) {
        product.getCategories().add(category);
        return product;
    }
}
```

By calling `saveCategoryInProduct`, you'll add new categories to the product entities. If Category entity contains `id` (not null) then new record will be created in `product_categories`  table.

However if `Category` entity does not have `id`( is null), then there will be an attempt to create new record in `category` table first, then associate it to provided product `id`(by creating record in `product_categories`). In this case you may encounter `DuplicateKeyException`. To deal with it you may modify `addCategory` method in a following way:

```
    private Product addCategory(Product product, Category category) {
        product.getCategories().add(
                categoryRepository
                        .findByName(category)
                        .orElse(category));
        return product;
    }
```

This way you'll make sure that the category you add either retrieved from db(therefore will not be created again) or does not exists yet.

Comment: Still not how sure to use your two new methods createProduct and saveCategoryInProduct. Should i just call both? or would it be ?

Comment: by adding just the hascode and equals method in Category didn't work

Comment: To test it just call `createProduct` first(it will create new `Product` record in database without any category associated with it), then call saveCategoryInProduct using `id` of newly created product, e.g: Product product = productService.createProduct(new Product(...)); productService.saveCategoryInProduct(product.getId, new Category(...))`

Comment: Overriding `hashCode` and `equals` may indirectly helps. Here is an example: imagine you've retrieved a product with categories(each category will have `id` and `name`), then you decide to create and add new category to `Set<Category>` with the same name, but without id(null). Without overriding hashCode it would be possible to have 2 categories with the same name in the Set field and usually you don't want this to happen, since it may cause DuplicateKeyException when `Product` entity will be saved. Probably this example isn't perfect, however I'm pretty sure that there might be other cases.

Comment: I did it as you suggested but the error still appears. When I try to create another product with the same cateogory it throws the error of duplicate key for category.